# Window not showing while using TYPE_APPLICATION in WindowManager

Tags: android, surfaceview, window-managers

Window not showing while adding surfaceview to windowmanager.  But it showing when I use TYPE_PHONE instead of TYPE_APPLICATION.

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) ctx.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);      
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams( 300,300,WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);  
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;  params.x = 0;  params.y = 100;  
windowManager.addView(surfaceView, params);
```

Comment: Please correct the title spelling